# XML name expected in Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm in my intro to VB programming class. So far it's going well, but I'm getting an error which doesn't, in my very limited time with the language, seem like it should be an error. So, fair warning, this is probably something simple going over my head. First, code snippet:

```
If total >= 0 AndAlso <= 20 Then
    payment = total * 10.00
    ElseIf total >= 21 AndAlso <= 30 Then
    payment = total * 12.00
    ElseIf total >=31 AndAlso <= 40 Then
    payment = total *15.00                            

    End If
```

In each of the <=, I get two error messages, but they're ONLY attached to the = portion. They are: element is missing an end tag and XML name expected.

What's up with this? Something germane to VB which causes that symbol to flub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't repeat the variable name.

```
ElseIf total >= 21 AndAlso <= 30 Then
```

should be

```
ElseIf total >= 21 AndAlso total <= 30 Then
```

The reason you're getting the XML error is that XML literals are valid in VB.Net.  For example:

```
Dim myData = <name>Sally</name>
Debug.Print(myData.Value)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the error either, but it's probably an error caused by the invalid syntax.

`AndAlso` doesn't quite work with the sytnax you've used. You need a full, valid expression on both sides:

```
if (total >= 0) AndAlso (total <= 20) Then
```

Note the use of the `total` variable on both sides of the `AndAlso` operator. (I've added the parentheses just for clarity.)

Comment: That was absolutely it. Thanks so much!